# JavaScript showing error

Tags: javascript, lightwindow

I have an accordion menu and a lightwindow script on my web page. The lightwindow script does not work because of the accordion script because if I delete the latter the lightwindow script works. There must be a conflict but what?
Here is the head section of my page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="lightwindow/javascript/prototype.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lightwindow/javascript/scriptaculous.js?load=effects"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lightwindow/javascript/lightwindow.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="lightwindow/css/lightwindow.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<!-- accordion scripts -->
<script src="js/jquery-1.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/menu.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.cookie.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/accordion.css" />
```

Comment: And what error is your JavaScript showing?

Comment: I presume that prototype conflicts with jquery. But the only thing you post is the head of your page. How do you call your lightwindow?

Comment: you mix jquery and prototype libraries, this can be source of troubles

Answer (score 0):

This shit happens when using too much libraries and plugins...

Try use the noConflict function of jQuery so you can use prototype and scriptaculous with it. The [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) says :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="other_lib.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $.noConflict();
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // Code that uses jQuery's $ can follow here.
  });
  // Code that uses other library's $ can follow here.
</script>
```

But honestly, if i were you, i would choose ONE library i would use for my website, find plugins that do the same since it's damn full of plugins out there.

Also, update jQuery call to something like :

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/jquery.min.js"><\/script>')
```

Answer (score 0):

#### You are loading both `prototype.js` and `jquery.js`.

Use **jQuery** using `noConflict`.

```
$.noConflict();
```

And replace all the instances of `$` for jQuery with `jQuery`.